# Minifilter prevent new file created with warning dialog

Tags: filesystems, driver, pass-through, minifilter

I has written a minifilter in kernel mode.
I want to prevent creating a new file on USB. But when I used:

```
[CODE]
    FltCancelFileOpen( FltObjects->Instance, FltObjects->FileObject );
    Data->IoStatus.Status = STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED; 
    Data->IoStatus.Information = 0;
    return FLT_PREOP_COMPLETE;
[CODE]
```

=> I could prevent creating a new file. But It always show warning dialog.
What should i do to NOT show this dialog?

**UPDATED: 2014/12/22**

I am writing a fs minifilter driver for an sittuation. When User drag & drop a file or folder to USB (example H:)

1. The driver will get file's information;
   ==> Done
2. The driver will delete this file or folder (No file/ folder will be created on USB)

    - I just want to catch event to start app (3)

    - The files will be deleted before created on USB.

   **==> Done
3. Do something.

=> Please give me an advice for this sittuation? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I could solve my issue by redirect open another file

1. First, define new unicode string newfile = "abcdef.txt";
2. Using FltGetFileNameInformation to get file name information
3. Using FltParseFileNameInformation to pares it.
4. Get file name which format : \Device\HarddiskVolume1[path_to_file]filename[.ext]
5. Then, split it to part: \Device\HarddiskVolume1[path_to_file] and filename[.ext]
6. Append newfile to first part: \Device\HarddiskVolume1[path_to_file]abcdef.txt
7. Now I will open new file instead of old file as following:

   // Get old file name

   PUNICODE_STRING pFileName = &Data->Iopb->TargetFileObject->FileName;

   // Free release buffer

   ExFreePool(pFileName->Buffer);

   // Re-allocate buffer
   pFileName->Length = 0;
   pFileName->MaximumLength = redirectTargetFile.MaximumLength;
   pFileName->Buffer = (PWSTR) ExAllocatePool(NonPagedPool, pFileName->MaximumLength);

   // Assign new file name for it
   RtlCopyUnicodeString(pFileName, &unicode_string_new_file_name);
   // Tell the kernel to reparse this file open so it uses the new file path

   Data->IoStatus.Information = IO_REPARSE;
   Data->IoStatus.Status = STATUS_REPARSE;
   Data->Iopb->TargetFileObject->RelatedFileObject = NULL;

   FltSetCallbackDataDirty(Data);
   return FLT_PREOP_SUCCESS_WITH_CALLBACK;

Reference http://www.codingnotebook.com/2013/05/redirect-file-open-using-windows.html

Answer (score 0):

No you can't -- it's the originator of the request that decides how to react to the denied access. Potentially you could allow opening but prevent any writes, but this would confuse the application and the user.

Comment: **Eugene Mayevski 'EldoS**!
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Do you know another ways for this sittuation?

Comment: @GSP Sorry, I can't think of any at the moment. You either return error (which is then reported to the user) or report success in which case the application tries to continue the operation.

Comment: Mayevski 'EldoS! Thank you very much.